# 'Save and Copy to all communities' resets profile picture if it's set to Gravatar

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture, identicon

I recently updated my profile bio (from Arqade) and clicked 'Save and copy changes to all public communities'.

This appears to have broken/reset my profile picture on all but Arqade.

Note that I did not update my profile picture as part of my changes.

**Arqade:**
[image: Arqade SE Profile]

**Meta SE for comparison:**
[image: Meta SE Profile]

I haven't touched my profile picture in years. Is this a bug?

---

**Update:** It appears my profile pic across all communities has been set back to 'Identicon'. I went on to Stack Overflow and changed my profile picture back to 'Gravitar' and clicked 'Save and copy to all communities' again, but this did not update my profile picture anywhere but SO. (I did the same on Sustainability to be doubly sure).

**Update 2:** This is a persistent bug - I had changed most of my SE communities back to my 'Robotnik' display pic over the past little while. Today I edited my profile again on Arqade, Clicked 'Save and copy' - and the display pic reverted back to identicon again across all sites.

**Update 3:** I have re-uploaded my profile picture and the 'Save and copy' function worked. It appears that this is actually a bug to do with the old images from Gravatar.

Comment: I had the same problem when changing my user name. Using an uploaded picture and "save and copy to all communities" finally solved it for me

Comment: I hit the same issue as well

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I now have to individually switch back from Identicon to Gravitar on every site.

Comment: This just happened to me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've (finally) fixed this bug, so you should be able to make changes to your profile picture and successfully propagate those changes to other communities. It turns out that `null` and `""` are two different things? Who knew?? (We leave the profile image URL column `null` for Gravatar images everywhere except for the place in which we store profile defaults.) Thanks so much for reporting and for your patience!

Comment: This type of error got me so many times in VBA.